# On Fedora - how do I find (configuration-)files which have been altered since installation?

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, dnf

I'm currently observing a problem with my onboard sound device (popular NUC device) and I found no fix for this yet. So I'm currently "hoping" I've made some modifications on some configuration file in the past which now causes the problem.

But how would I find those modifications? I can't remember fiddling with my configuration files int the first place.

Apart from comparing to a parallel installation of my OS manually - does Fedora provide some way to find modifications of files which have been installed with `dnf`?
The most sophisticated way I guess would be a way to find only modifications on configuration files but if I had the chance to compare *all* files installed by `dnf` with their original ones that would be great, too..

So the short version of my question is:

- is there a way to find modifications on installed files with Fedora/`dnf`?
- or: is there a way to get the contents of all files installed by `dnf`?
- how do I otherwise find differences to a freshly installed Fedora?

My current approach would be to store the contents of `/etc/` and `/usr` and reinstall all packages but I'm afraid this would be even more work than a fresh install..

Comment: Does looking at the file modified dates help? In future I recommend adding a comment to config files that you change. I normally comment out the original line, add a comment with the date and why I made the change, then write a new config line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files which has been altered:

```
rpm -V NAMEOFPACKAGE
```

All files which has been altered:

```
rpm -Va
```

All altered configs from package `NAMEOFPACKAGE`:

```
rpm -Vc NAMEOFPACKAGE
```

How to find the difference from stock config. There is many way. IMO the easiest is:

```
dnf reinstall NAMEOFPACKAGE
dnf install rpmconf
rpmconf --owner=NAMEOFPACKAGE
```

The reinstall will pull down the original config and save it as *.rpmnew or *.rpmsave. Rpmconf will find the difference and allow you to see the diff or merge it.

Comment: I admit that I could have taken that from the documentation - at least `dnf -V`. The `rpmconf` part is very helpful and something I would not have looked for!